# Existence of global section, étale map and totally disconnected space

Tags: gn.general-topology, fibre-bundles, homeomorphism

I am trying to show the following result :

Let $Y$ be a totally disconnected space and compact space, $X$ a locally compact space and $p:Y\to X$ a surjective local homeomorphism. Then, there exist continuous map $s:X\to Y$ such that $p\circ s=id_X$.

I just don't know how to start.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: If you assume the spaces are metrizable, then it follows from the zero-dimensional Michael selection theorems. See Theorem 2.4 here: http://www.pef.uni-lj.si/repovs/knjige/book/zero_dimensional.pdf. Note that $p$ is continuous so $X$ is compact (hence paracompact). Further, $Y$ is zero-dimensional and hence $X$ is zero-dimensional as well. Hence the theorem can be applied to the multi-valued "pre-image map" $X\to Y$.